# Shiny R: Populate a list from input and return list on output via reactive

Tags: r, list, shiny

I try to populate a list on shiny with the elements of the list passed over from a shiny input. The list should accumulate all the made choices. The list should finally be sent to the shiny output. Actually I already get a list which I can send to output. This list is however always just of length one and this single element gets updated as the input does. Actually I am only interested in the "names" of the list, this is why I assign the value 1 to each name element:

UI.R

```
shinyUI(
    fluidRow(   
        column(1,
            # reactive input 
            selectInput("Input1", 
                        label = "Select Parameter 1",
                        choices = c("none",letters[1:16]),
                        multiple = T),
            selectInput("Input2", 
                        label = "Select Parameter 2",        
                        choices = c("none",c(1:24) )
                        multiple = T),        
            # printout of list
            htmlOutput("printoutList")
        ) # end of column
    ) # end of fluid row
) # end of Shiny UI
```

Shiny.R

```
# create an empty list
container <- list()
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    # pass over input to reactive
    inputInfo <- reactive({
        if(input$Input1 == "none" | input$Input2 == "none") {
            "-"               
        } else { 
            paste(input$Input1 ,input$Input2, sep = "")
        }
    }) 

    # fill list and pass over list to output 
    output$printoutList <- renderUI({                    
        container[[inputInfo()]] <- 1
        paste("You have chosen: ", names(container), sep = "")        
    }) 

)} #end of shinyServer function
```

Any idea how to solve this? I already tried around a lot... unfortunately I am quite new to R, especially to shiny ! I would really appreciate any kind of help! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

include the multiple = TRUE argument for selectInput

```
 selectInput("Input1", 

          label = "Select Parameter 1",
          choices = c("none",letters[1:16]),
          multiple = TRUE

          )
```

But also it seems like your server and ui files are mixed up and you don't have the shinyServer function in the code.

Comment: Thank you James for your answer! You are right, I had some copy paste errors in my script, sorry for that one. Unfortunately I do still get an error message with your edit: Warning in run(timeoutMs) :

Comment: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, flaggedWell(), value = c("b3", "e5", "g8")) : 
  no such index at level 1

Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: First I would add the the selected = "none" argument to the selectInput function So that it is not returning NULL . Also you can use the validate function to make sure you are passing appropriate inputs.